# How to support i18n with kotlin js

Tags: internationalization, kotlin-js

i'm currently trying to add i18n support to a kotlin js project (no react).

```
return document.create.div {
        span("mid-title") {
            +i18n here (ResourceBundle.getBundle()?)
        }....
```

- Added resource bundle files (strings.properties, strings_en.properties)
- Tried to get them via ResourceBundle.getBundle <- kotlin doesn't know how to use
- Found a [github](https://github.com/edwardsCam/i18nliner-kt)  but dont like that approach

So is there a convenient way that works with kotlin js?

Update:

```
 fun loadJSON(callback: (response: String) -> Unit) {
    val xobj = XMLHttpRequest()
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json")
    xobj.open("GET", "test.json", true)
    xobj.onreadystatechange = {

        if (xobj.readyState.toInt() == 4 && xobj.status.toInt() == 200) {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback
            // as .open() will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    }
    xobj.send(null)
}
```

Update 2:

Got it now

So like I wrote before i'm using javascript to load the file. After that I have the Json object where I can get the value by key. I've also added an overload to replace arguments in the string. Further I've added an MuatableStateFlow var to observe the loading state of the language. But keep in mind that this concept always needs to run on a server. Locally you get a CORS error

Comment: I believe that ResourceBundle is JVM specific, for Kotlin/JS, I think, you can try any JS i18n library.

Comment: Also, you can find some kotlin multiplatform solution, e.g. https://github.com/fluidsonic/fluid-i18n

Comment: definitly interesting the usage of fluid but not for my kind of use. We are working with transifex, so i need a way to get our own defs from json or properties file. Currently I'm trying the javasrcipt approach. Updated

Comment: @coffeLord Can you provide me some sample repo. I am trying to implement same and having trouble setting up. Also i am using maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class LanguageSupport(private val folder: String = "", private val lang: String) {
    private lateinit var currentLang: Json

    private val languageMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<LanguageSupportState>(
        LanguageSupportState.LanguageInit
    )
    val languageStateFlow: StateFlow<LanguageSupportState> = languageMutableStateFlow

    init {
        loadJSON()
    }

    fun get(key: String): String {
        val value = currentLang[key]
        check(value != null) {
            throw Exception("key not found to load language definition")
        }
        return if (value is String) {
            value
        } else {
            throw Exception("value of key is not a string")
        }
    }

    fun get(key: String, vararg placeholders: String): String {
        val value = currentLang[key]
        check(value != null) {
            throw Exception("key not found to load language definition")
        }
        return if (value is String) {
            var finalValue: String = value
            for (item in placeholders) {
                finalValue = finalValue.replaceFirst(PLACEHOLDER, item)
            }
            finalValue
        } else {
            throw Exception("value of key is not a string")
        }
    }

    private fun loadJSON() {
        val xobj = XMLHttpRequest()
        xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json")
        xobj.open("GET", "${folder}test_${lang}.json", true)
        xobj.onreadystatechange = {

            if (xobj.readyState.toInt() == 4 && xobj.status.toInt() == 200) {
                // Required use of an anonymous callback
                // as .open() will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
                currentLang = JSON.parse(xobj.responseText)
                languageMutableStateFlow.value = LanguageSupportState.LanguageLoaded
            }
        }
        xobj.send(null)
    }

    companion object {
        const val PLACEHOLDER = "%s"
    }
}

sealed class LanguageSupportState {
    object LanguageLoaded : LanguageSupportState()
    object LanguageError : LanguageSupportState()
    object LanguageInit : LanguageSupportState()
}
```

And because I use Koin

```
single { (folder: String, language: String) ->
        LanguageSupport(
            folder = folder,
            lang = language,
        )
    }
```